# Нужно ли выделять запятыми словосочетание "в возможно короткий срок"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, деловой-язык

**Прошу Вас, в возможно короткий срок, подготовить и направить ответ заявителю.**

Нужны ли запятые в данном предложении?

Answer (score 3):

Выражение *в возможно короткий срок* используется в деловом (официальном) языке.
Выступает [в значении наречия](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/13417/%D0%B2) (как? насколько быстро? как скоро?): быстро, скоро, как можно быстрее, не тратя времени даром, не теряя времени...
Запятыми не выделяется. Вот некоторые примеры использования.

*В связи с тем, что сроки, установленные Гражданским процессуальным кодексом уже давно истекли, прошу Вас в возможно короткий срок предоставить сведения о причинах оставления искового заявления без движения* (из судебной переписки).

*Настоящий пакт подлежит ратификации в возможно короткий срок. Обмен ратификационными грамотами должен произойти в Токио также в возможно короткий срок.*
[Пакт о нейтралитете между СССР и Японией](https://www.runivers.ru/doc/d2.php?SECTION_ID=6770&CENTER_ELEMENT_ID=147035&PORTAL_ID=7149)

Answer (score 2):

**В деловом стиле не принято использование уточняющих оборотов**, вся информация излагается в основном сообщении:

Прошу Вас **в возможно короткий срок** подготовить и направить ответ заявителю.

**Вопрос № 295857**
Просим Вас в связи со сложившейся ситуацией осуществить **в возможно короткие сроки** передачу объекта

Добрый день. Подскажите пожалуйста, нужны ли этом предложении запятые. заранее спасибо.

Ответ справочной службы русского языка: **Запятые не нужны**.

**Пример с обособлением** значительно распространенного уточняющего оборота **в виде исключения:**

О таковой ратификации, в **возможно короткий срок и во всяком случае не позднее как через пятьдесят дней со дня подписания договора**, будет взаимно сообщено императорским правительствам российскому и японскому...  Портсмутский мирный договор между Россией и Японией (1905)]

Answer (score 0):

Запятые не нужны - нет причин для постановки.

Comment: Разве это не уточняющее обстоятельство, которое выделяется запятыми?